# Trying to create document.createElement('script') with Google analyatics 4 function inside

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, createelement

Im moving my site over to GoogleAnalytics 4 and I need to add the below script to the page. Im using JS to add it to the head if the accept cookies button has been clicked.

HTML from given to me by Google

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer', {GA-ID});</script>
```

I created a script tag and tried to just insert the function between the script tags but that didn't work, is the a different way i should/could be adding the function inbetween the script tags?

```
const gtagManager = document.createElement('script')

      gtagManager.onload = () => {
        (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f)
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', {GA-ID})
      }

document.head.appendChild(gtagManager)
```

Comment: why did you inject an arrow function there?

Comment: @BNazaruk was just how id seen it down on another code example

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
  w[l] = w[l] || [];
  w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j = d.createElement(s),
    dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
  j.async = true;
  j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
  j.onload = function(){ // execute your code here }
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "G-123456789");
</script>
```

I used to insert onload function inside the script. You can try it work or not on your end.